# Copy row from table 1 to table 2

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need to copy a row from my table1 to my table2.
I have a select that lists all the entries in an `<option>` from the table1, and when I choose an option, it needs to be inserted in the row (with the same name) in table2.

**Trying to be more specific:**

It's a form with fields that are inserted in table2, but one field is an option that lists the entries from table1. When they get submitted, they'll be put in table2, including the chosen option from table1.

Could anyone help with this issue, please?

Table2 HTML form:

```
<div class="form">
//Simple input that's normaly inserted in table2
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<input class="form1" type="text" value="NAME" name="name" onfocus="if (this.value=='NAME') this.value='';"/>
 <br />
//Input that lists all the entries from the "companies" field from table1
<select class="form7" value="COMPANIES" name="companies" />
<?php
//Connection DB file with the two databases (already tested)
include("connect.php");

//Select to list all the entries from "companies" row from table1                            
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1 ORDER BY nomefantasia") or die(mysql_error());

while($array = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
//Option listing field
echo    '<option value="companies" name="companies">'.$array['companies'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
//Submit button
<input class="button" type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />
</form>
```

INSERT INTO file

```
<?php

include("connect.php");

// Get values from form
$name=$_POST['name'];

// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $table2(name) VALUES ('$name')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
echo "Done!!";
echo "<br />";
echo "<a href='#'>Return</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

So, how do I call the "companies" row into that?

Comment: Have you got any code we can look at for what you've got so far?

Comment: Yes! I just edited my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of the two tables are the same you just do:

```
INSERT INTO table2
SELECT * FROM table1;
```

Or we can copy only the columns we want to into another, existing table:

```
INSERT INTO table2
(column_name(s))
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1;
```

Comment: Anderson, tentei exatamente o exemplo citado há algum tempo, mas não consegui imaginar como funcionaria. Acabei de editar a pergunta e inseri o meu código, o problema está sendo o < select >, que lista as entradas da coluna "companies" da table1, e quando um < option > é selecionado, este precisa aparecer na coluna "companies" da table2.

Comment: Anne, em seu código o option do select no atributo `value` coloque o id da companie e antes de fazer o insert na table2 selecione a linha da table1 que contenha este valor e use o código que mencionei.

Comment: Eu não posso selecionar um único ID de uma company, porque todas elas são listadas no <option>, e quando eu escolher uma destas, a informação será inserida na table2. Da forma que falou, a coluna "companies" da table2 aparece somente o nome do option, que é "companies", e não o valor dela (o que foi escolhido na lista). :(

Comment: Anna, Se você não puder alterar o atributo `value` do `option` você terá que recorrer a outros recursos como por exemplo javascript. Assim você poderá colocar outro atributo no `option` e através de javascript preencher um `input` `hidden` por exemplo e utilizá-lo no post.

Comment: Anderson, eu não consegui entender o que você quis dizer. Qual influência o "value" do input tem? Eu consigo listar o conteúdo a coluna, mas preciso que, ao selecionar uma dessas opções listadas pelo option, ela seja inserida em outra coluna, de outra tabela.

Comment: Anna, você fará isto através de um post correto ? .Para isso você precisa descobrir qual companie foi selecionada, por isso a influência do `value`. Da forma que esta fazendo o post sempre será `value="companies"`

Comment: Anderson, consegui! Eu usei o mesmo array em "values" e fiz algumas modificações nele. No final, nem acabou precisando mexer no select.

Se quiser, replica a sua pergunta como resposta oficial ao thread, pra eu te qualificar, ok? Obrigada!

Comment: Ok Anna fico feliz que tenha conseguido. Abraços